# Distribution List as Mailing List (change To Field) in Exchange Online

Tags: exchange

I want to use a distribution list in Exchange as mailing list. For this to accomplish, I need to change To field to point to the individual recipient rather than the list mail.

Example:
I send a mail to list@example.org. This gets delivered to user@example.org. The To Address is list@example.org. I want the To Address to be user@example.org. (The user shall not notice the existence of the mailing list).

I checked the "Rules" config - doesn't seem to provide any valuable settings.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Is the mailing list on the Exchange server or in the client, and what is the email client (Outlook?).

Comment: The distribution list is server-side (Exchange Admin Center)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a distribution list in Exchange as a mailing list, you will need to set up a rule in the Exchange Transport Rules. This will allow you to set the To field to point to the individual recipients rather than the list mail.

You can find more information about Exchange Transport Rules here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-rules/transport-rules-overview.

Comment: Hm, I can rewrite the `To` field via a transport rule, but what should I type in there? Since it is a mailing list, I need a placeholder for the current member - but it looks like I can only hardcode it to a one address.